# My Battery Precentage keeps going Up and Down?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, power-management, asus, battery

I recently started using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on my Asus K53E laptop, and it was working pretty well since September. But in November I noticed the original battery started get old & hold less of a charge when it hits 100%. So I decided to get a new OEM battery. Once I received the battery in December, the computer started to hold a charge longer and thought that corrected the issue. However what became worse is that every time I unplug the A/C from charging the laptop, it will show the charge Percentage jump up and down; at least until the laptop just shuts off from how inaccurate the battery's charge is. I'm not sure what it could be, but suggestions are welcomed.